# Tensorflow LSTM PTB Example - Understanding forward and backward pass

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

Right now I am going through the tensorflow example on LSTMs where they use the PTB dataset to create an LSTM network capable of predicting the next word. I've spent a lot of time trying to understand the code, and have a good understanding for most of it however there is one function which I don't fully grasp:

```
    def run_epoch(session, model, eval_op=None, verbose=False):
  """Runs the model on the given data."""
  costs = 0.0
  iters = 0
  state = session.run(model.initial_state)

  fetches = {
      "cost": model.cost,
      "final_state": model.final_state,
  }
  if eval_op is not None:
    fetches["eval_op"] = eval_op

  for step in range(model.input.epoch_size):
    feed_dict = {}
    for i, (c, h) in enumerate(model.initial_state):
      feed_dict[c] = state[i].c
      feed_dict[h] = state[i].h

    vals = session.run(fetches, feed_dict)
    cost = vals["cost"]
    state = vals["final_state"]

    costs += cost
    iters += model.input.num_steps    

  return np.exp(costs / iters)
```

My confusion is this: each time through the outerloop I believe we have processed batch_size * num_steps numbers of words, done the forward propagation and done the backward propagation. But, how in the next iteration, for example, do we know to start with the 36th word of each batch if num_steps = 35?  I suspect it is some change in an attribute of the class model on each iteration but I cannot figure that out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at `reader` https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/reader.py , this is a class responsible for producing your data (and actual slicing)

Comment: I had looked at that earlier to become more familiar with the structure of the data, but still I do not see what is changing each iteration through the outer for loop of the `run_epoch` function that we know to process new data when we run the operations in the `fetches` dictionary

Comment: nothing really changes, the reader itself controls where it is through the queue (look at `i` variable there). Each time you read something, you move the internal counter - so you do not need to change anything in the "outer" code, the inner one is incremental, just like file descriptors "move on their own" when you call "read" on them.

Comment: thanks, for clarifying that. so in the `ptb_producer` function i am creating `i` chunks of data that will be in a queue? and in the main program when i am done processing one chunk of data, i then move on to the next automatically by moving up the queue?